# How do I get a list of reactions from a message on discord.py rewrite?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm making a giveaway bot and I'm stuck at trying to get the reaction list of a message. How do I do that?

I've already tried `ctx.message.reactions` and `message.reactions`(message in this case is a variable that contains a `await channel.fetch_message(messageID)`).

```py
async def stopgiveaway(ctx, messageID):
    reaction = []
    guild = bot.get_guild(g_id) #    g_id is the guild id
    channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id) #    same as g_id but for channel 
    message = await channel.fetch_message(messageID)
    reaction = reaction.append(ctx.message.reactions)
    users = reaction.users(limit=None, after=None)
```

I'm not an expert in python or discord.py, I'm still learning, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do?  [`message.reactions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.reactions) will be the list of reactions on the message, what are you trying to do with that list?

Answer (score 2):

```
reaction = reaction.append(ctx.message.reactions)
```

This line is wrong; `reaction.append` already modifies the `reaction` list *in-place* and returns `None`, so the assignment replaces your list with `None`. But it's really not clear how you're expecting this to work anyway; `ctx.message.reactions` is already a list, so you probably don't really want to `append` it to another list (as a nested list), and either way a list doesn't have a `.users` method.

Comment: Reviewing the documentation: `ctx.message.reactions` is a list of `Reaction`s; it's the individual underlying `Reaction`s that have a `.users` method - so you'll need to do the iteration yourself.