# Problems with discord.py (collecting reactions and then iterating through the users who reacted)

Tags: python, discord.py

so I'm making a bot in discord.py, and I've stumbled on a problem.

Here's my code:

```
async def make_event(ctx):
    with open('stats.json', "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    event_embed = discord.Embed(title="AN EVENT IS HAPPENING!", description="React to the message to gain some coins!", color=discord.Colour.red())
    
    event_message = await ctx.send(embed=event_embed)
    await event_message.add_reaction("")
    await asyncio.sleep(4)
    reactors = []
    for reaction in event_message.reactions:
        
        reactorsForThatReaction = await reaction.users().flatten()
        
        for user in reactorsForThatReaction:
            if str(user.id) not in reactors:
                reactors.append(str(user.id))
    resultEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Event results",  description="The following users won coins:")
    for user in reactors:
        gain = random.randint(5000, 100000)
        users[user]["cash"] += gain
        formattedGain = "{:,}".format(gain)
        resultEmbed.add_field(name=client.fetch_user(int(user)).name, value=f"{formattedGain} cash.")

    await ctx.send(embed=resultEmbed)
```

Basically what this code does is make and send an embed (which users react to), and the bot processes those reactions and gives out coins. The problem that I have is that the bot isn't registering `event_message.reactions` at all. When I try print out `event_message.reactions`, it returns an empty list. I don't know what's going on here.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to fetch the message again, since now you are using the old message info before the sleep.

Before the use of `reactions` fetch the message like this

```py
event_message = await ctx.fetch_message(event_message.id)
```

[`Context.fetch_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.fetch_message)

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I get it now. I had an inkling that that might be the cause, but you explaining it makes it much easier to  understand. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56569432/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-reactions-from-a-message-on-discord-py-rewrite) that might help you. Basically, instead of using `event_message`, you can get the reactions using `ctx.message.reactions`

Comment: This was helpful too!